Power supply issues for poor man's SONOFF
So I have zero electronics education.  I've created some devices just following YouTube videos and what I call a bit of common sense.  Long story, but basically found that I could purchase D1 Mini's (ESP8266), relays, touch sensors, etc., and make my own "SONOFFs".
One of my first lessons was noise from a cheap USB power source.  Started using HiLink power supplies and all worked well.  Now I wanted to upgrade and run wires through my house with 24 V with battery backup, so I can keep internet/network if power goes out.
I replaced two HiLink power supplies with the 24 V power supply using a step-down converter.  Those are working as before.  However, when I replaced a third power supply with a step-down converter, my device started acting all weird.  Spent about 3 hours of troubleshooting before I realized that it is noise issues.
I am probably doing many things wrong, so hopefully some of you guys that know much more than me can help me correct some of my mistakes.
For the D1 minis I don't use any capacitors, resistors, etc. I just connect the 5 V power source to the 5v inputs of the D1 mini.  Usually I have the D1 mini in the switch wall plate, then run Cat 5 cable to the ceiling where I have the power supply and the relays.
The two Tasmotas that are working fine with the buck converter only have one touch sensor, and cable length is less than 15 feet.  The Tasmota that isn't working with the step-down converter has 2 touch sensors, 2 switches, about I would say about 30 feet of wire.  This device controls upstairs hall light, stairs light, dinning room light and kitchen light.
With that in mind, is there anything I could do to try and clean the noise?  Since the other two Tasmotas work fine, I am thinking the main issue is the length of the Cat 5 cable?  Should I just redo the setup using two D1 mini's instead of one, that way I can get rid of the long cable run I have now?
Thanks in advance for any and all suggestions.

I have no idea what any of these names mean: "D1 Mini's (esp8266)", "HiLInk", "tasmota", "sonoff".  Are these all brand names?  Links to the products, and a wiring diagram would greatly help us to help you.

Sorry about that.  I mostly spend time on smart home forums, and the stuff I mentioned are all pretty much smart home related items.
D1 Mini is a variant of the ESP32 chip.  https://naylampmechatronics.com/espressif-esp/291-wemos-d1-mini-esp8266-wifi.html
Hilink is a 5v power source https://www.hlktech.net/index.php?id=105
Tasmota is the name of the software that is flashed on the esp8266.  Sonoff is a brand name. Their popular device is the "sonoff basic", which is basically an esp8266, a small power supply, and relay.

May I suggest to edit your question to include all of that new information.  Cheers.

"Zero electronic education" and you are building smart home stuff that likely connects to mains voltage? Are you an electrician and legally allowed to work on residential mains wiring (you might not be if you rent instead of own) and are your wiring done to legal requirements of your local jurisdiction? If something happens, like an Aliexpress bought relay starts a fire, you might be in trouble regarding insurance people.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Justme, yes the stuff I am playing with pretty much all directly or indirectly connects to the mains voltage.  I do understand basics, like amps, voltage, watts.
I live in Mexico, and often here we get to be jack of all trades, master of none.  For what it is worth when I started to check out our wiring that was installed by so called "professionals" I noticed ground was tied up with neutral in couple of different boxes.  That is wrong, or at least wouldn't pass code in USA, as you only tie up ground with neutral at the main (first) box.

@justme, if I lived in USA I probably wouldn't do what I am doing here in Mexico. Here in Mexico pretty much all homes are made 100% with centerblocks and cement.  If the cheap aliexpress relay starts a fire at worst it would just destroy the electrical cables, but the house itself would never catch fire.  In USA a short circuit in the ceiling could easily burn down a whole house.

You need to be more precise explaining exactly what power supplies, cabling etc you are using. Your setup is a whole lot more complex than you imagine so small details matter. A buck converter is a step down converter and they are all not the same, so we need a part number, picture or other information that allows us to understand exactly what you’re referring to.
